# Program doesn't run - it opens and closes

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

I have a problem with my main program to which after all the calls I make after running the program it just opens then closes. It doesn't find any error in my code or anything, so I tried creating a new project and it does the same thing with no error.

I even tried example code:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain (HINSTANCE ...)
    ShellExecute(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"open", (LPCWSTR)"cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

and it still just opens and closes. What is the issue here? I can provide the output log if necessary but I have no idea.

Comment: Programs run, and when they've completed all their instructions, they close. Can you show the complete program and indicate why you believe it should remain open for longer than it does.

Comment: As for the code in the question, it is quite wrong. Casting a `const char*` to a `const wchar_t*` does not make it so. Everytime you use a cast, you should be concerned. You need to use wide literals: `L"open"`. You also claim that there are no errors. But I don't see any evidence of you checking for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Shouldn't it open cmd.exe when it executes? It doesn't do this, so how does that mean that it compiled? When I execute the application from release it should execute cmd.exe - no? I mean that is what I prompted it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean about opening and closing. But this code is very wrong:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"open", (LPCWSTR)"cmd.exe", 
    NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

The casts are no good. The two string literals are pointers to arrays of `char` casting them to `const wchar_t*` doesn't change what they are. It just asks the compiler to trust that you know better than it does. You don't. They are really not `const wchar_t*`. All your cast achieves is to allow you to break type safety and convert an informative compile time error into a cryptic run time failure. Until you have a deep understanding of the language you should refrain from casting.

You need to use wide literals:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

You also appear to be doing no error checking. That's quite hard with `ShellExecute`. Try `ShellExecuteEx` instead and take heed of the value it returns.

Comment: ShellExecuteEx showed me exactly what my error was while debugging it with OllyDbg -> It helped me understand... thanks